# Vscode shows "exception has occurred"

Tags: c++

The code below shows "segmentation fault" on this line`if (shortlist[i].deadline < (*s).deadline)`
Whats the problem ?

```
    #include <iostream>

    #include <vector>

    #include <algorithm>

    using namespace std;

    class task
    {

    public:
        int profit;

        int deadline;

        int number;
    };

    bool by_profit(const task &left, const task &right)
    {

        return left.profit > right.profit;
    }

    void schedule(int num, vector<task> shortlist, vector<task> &result)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < num; i++)
        {

            bool largest = 1;

            vector<task>::iterator s = result.begin();

            for (; s != result.end(); s++)
            {

                if (shortlist[i].deadline < (*s).deadline)
                {

                    largest = 0;

                    break;
                    
                }
            }
            if (largest == 0)
            {

                result.insert(s, shortlist[i]);
            }
            else
            {

                result.push_back(shortlist[i]);

                s = --result.end();
            }

            for (int e = 0; e < result.size(); e++)
            {
                if (result[e].deadline > e + 1)
                {

                    result.erase(s);
                }
            }
        }
        for (task a : result)
        {

            cout << a.number;
        }
    }

    int main()
    {

        int num;

        cin >> num;

        vector<task> shortlist;

        shortlist.reserve(num);

        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {

            cin >> shortlist[i].profit >> shortlist[i].deadline;

            shortlist[i].number = i + 1;
        }

        vector<task> result;

        result.reserve(num);

        result.push_back(shortlist[0]);

        sort(shortlist.begin(), shortlist.end(), by_profit);

        schedule(num, shortlist, result); // 7 40 3 35 1 30 1 25 3 20 1 15 3 10 2

        system("pause");

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

reserve is not the same as resize.

So your loop where you try to fill shortlist is invalid.

Reserve only allocated the memory, but doesn't change the size. So you still have to you push_back.

On the other end, resize does both (at the cost of potentially initializing each element).

So either use push back in your loop, or replace your first reserve by a resize.